# Creating Graphs in Python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface

I have created a GUI in which I read a CSV file and calculate the liquid output from the data. Now I want to do two things:
1) I want to generate the output based on **time** just like date
2) I want to generate graphs on a separate window in my GUI for a user specific time or date

This is my code:

```
import csv
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showwarning, showinfo
import datetime

#csv_file = csv.reader(open("C:\Users\Lala Rushan\Downloads\ARIF Drop Monitoring Final\ARIF Drop Monitoring Final\DataLog.csv"))
from Tools.scripts.treesync import raw_input
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)


        button1 = Button(self, text="Browse for a file", command=self.askfilename)
        button2 = Button(self, text="Count the file", command=self.takedate)
        button3 = Button(self, text="Exit", command=master.destroy)
        button1.grid()
        button2.grid()
        button3.grid()
        self.userInputFromRaw = Entry(self)
        self.userInputFromRaw.grid()

        self.userInputToRaw = Entry(self)
        self.userInputToRaw.grid()

        self.grid()

    def askfilename(self):
        in_file = askopenfilename()
        if not in_file.endswith(('.CSV')):
            showwarning('Are you trying to annoy me?', 'How about giving me a CSV file, genius?')
        else:
            self.in_file=in_file

    def CsvImport(self,csv_file):


        dist = 0
        for row in csv_file:
            _dist = row[0]
            try:
                _dist = float(_dist)
            except ValueError:
                _dist = 0

            dist += _dist
        print ("Urine Volume is: %.2f" % (_dist*0.05))


    def takedate(self):
        from_raw = self.userInputFromRaw.get()
        from_date = datetime.date(*map(int, from_raw.split('/')))
        print ('From date: = ' + str(from_date))
        to_raw = self.userInputToRaw.get()
        to_date = datetime.date(*map(int, to_raw.split('/')))
        in_file = ("H:\DataLog.csv")
        in_file= csv.reader(open(in_file,"r"))

        for line in in_file:
            _dist = line[0]
            try:
                file_date =  datetime.date(*map(int, line[1].split(' ')[1].split('/')))
                if from_date <= file_date <= to_date:
                    self.CsvImport(in_file)

            except IndexError:
                pass

root = Tk()
root.title("Urine Measurement")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

How can I achieve the above 2 tasks?

Comment: Most people would use MatPlotLib for something like that.

Comment: can you give an example of using matplotlib with my code? I am new to python so cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I must agree with Jacques de Hooge, you should be using `matplotlib` for that.
At the beggining of your file, import it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

As you only want to open a new window with the plot, a `matplotlib` window should suffice. You can use a scatter plot:

```
plt.scatter(X, Y)
```

Where `X` is an iteratable with the x coordinates and `Y` an iteratable with the y coordinates. Since you want to do something with a constant change in time, you can, having a `values` list with the values to plot, do the following:

```
plt.scatter(range(len(values)), values)
plt.show()
```

You might also want to run this inside a thread, so that the rest of the program doesn't "freeze" while the `matplotlib` window is open. There are plenty of places where this is explained.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just have one more confusion, on X axis i want to use date which comes from **takedate()** function and on y-axis i want to print output of liquid measurement which comes from **csvimport()** function. Where should i plot the graph? in the **__init__** function?