# How to display value from a function to a GUI widget in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have created a GUI in which I read the CSV file and then calculate the liquid output.in **CSVImport** function, there is a print statement where the output is calculated. I want to print this in my GUI with a text widget. How can i do that? My code is below:

```
import csv
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showwarning, showinfo
import datetime

#csv_file = csv.reader(open("C:\Users\Lala Rushan\Downloads\ARIF Drop Monitoring Final\ARIF Drop Monitoring Final\DataLog.csv"))
from Tools.scripts.treesync import raw_input
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)


        button1 = Button(self, text="Browse for a file", command=self.askfilename)
        button2 = Button(self, text="Measure The Urine", command=self.takedate)
        button3 = Button(self, text="Exit", command=master.destroy)
        button1.grid()
        button2.grid()
        button3.grid()
        l1 = Label(self, text="Enter from date (2017/01/01)")
        l1.grid()

        self.userInputFromRaw = Entry(self)
        self.userInputFromRaw.grid()
        l2 = Label(self, text="Enter to date (2017/01/01)")

        l2.grid()
        self.userInputToRaw = Entry(self)
        self.userInputToRaw.grid()



        self.grid()

    def askfilename(self):
        in_file = askopenfilename()
        if not in_file.endswith(('.CSV')):
            showwarning('Are you trying to annoy me?', 'How about giving me a CSV file, genius?')
        else:
            self.in_file=in_file

    def CsvImport(self,csv_file):


        dist = 0
        for row in csv_file:
            _dist = row[0]
            try:
                _dist = float(_dist)
            except ValueError:
                _dist = 0

            dist += _dist
        print ("Urine Volume is: %.2f" % (_dist*0.05))


    def takedate(self):
        from_raw = self.userInputFromRaw.get()
        from_date = datetime.date(*map(int, from_raw.split('/')))
        print ('From date: = ' + str(from_date))
        to_raw = self.userInputToRaw.get()
        to_date = datetime.date(*map(int, to_raw.split('/')))
        in_file = ("H:\DataLog.csv")
        in_file= csv.reader(open(in_file,"r"))

        for line in in_file:
            _dist = line[0]
            try:
                file_date =  datetime.date(*map(int, line[1].split(' ')[1].split('/')))
                if from_date <= file_date <= to_date:
                    self.CsvImport(in_file)

            except IndexError:
                pass

root = Tk()
root.title("Urine Measurement")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you must have a Text widget. In your `App.__init__` function, you should add something like the following:

```
self.output = Text(self)
self.output.grid()
```

To append text to the widget, you can use `Text.insert`; in your `App.CsvImport` function, you should replace the call to `print` with:

```
self.output.insert(END, "Urine Volume is: %.2f" % (_dist*0.05))
```

If you need some reference on the Tkinter Text Widget, [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) might be of help, along with the various questions here on StackOverflow.

---

It is also worth noting that since you are displaying only one line, it might be more convenient to use a `Label`. Create the label normally, and when you want to change it's text, you can use:

```
self.output["text"] = "Urine Volume is: %.2f" % (_dist*0.05)
```

Comment: great that worked like a charm. can you also answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252096/creating-graphs-in-python-gui]

Comment: @rushan: Answered that too, even though it would be easy enough to google "insert text into tkinter text widget" or "matplotlib plot data". You should **always** search what you are looking for before asking something here on StackOverflow. It isn't because you are a beginner that you shouldn't do so.